# Sequences and series and what is good enough

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

It seems like so much of this is based on intuition and assumptions. I don't understand the limit comparison test contrapositives so I ignore the limit comparison test as it seems largely useless and cumbersome.

In trying to find the convergence or divergence of $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + \ln n}$ why is it wrong to use the comparison test? I know that this can't converge because lnn is much smaller than $n^\frac{1}{2}$ so by p series it could never converge.

$\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + \ln n} > \sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + n^\frac{1}{4}}$ and that $.5 + .25 < 1$ so by p series it diverges and it is a smaller function so by comparison test it diverges.

Everyone says this is wrong, but how accurate and precise do I need to be because it seems like a cumbersome approach like the limit comparison test makes just as many assumptions.

Comment: Why was the $n^\frac{1}{2}$ replaced by the $n^\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: How does $.5 + .25 < 1$ show the series diverge?

Comment: @Makoto: As for the replacement, $\ln n$ is also smaller than $n^{1/4}$ for large enough $n,$ so that isn't particularly problematic. As for the inequality mentioned, it doesn't show that the series diverges, but his approach is still on the right track, even though it took a detour near the end.

Comment: @CameronBuie If he hadn't replaced $n^\frac{1}{2}$ by $n^\frac{1}{4}$,
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{1/2}+n^{1/4}}$ would have been a lot simpler.

Comment: @Makoto: True. Still, he was nearly there, despite the slightly inefficient approach.

Comment: @CameronBuie I guess he replaced $n^\frac{1}{2}$ by $n^\frac{1}{4}$ to use $.5 + .25 < 1$.
But this does not help to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{1/2}+n^{1/4}}$ diverges.
This is where he is wrong.

Comment: Why is that wrong? It seems to hold true for all n

Comment: @PaulthePirate His logic is wrong. $.5 + .25 < 1$ has nothing to do with the divergence of the series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot apply the $p$-series result to $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{1/2}+n^{1/4}},$$ since it is not a $p$-series.

However, you're nearly there. Noting that for $n\ge 1$ we have $2n^{1/2}\ge n^{1/2}+n^{1/4}$ then we have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{1/2}+n^{1/4}}\ge\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{1/2}}.$$ **Now** you can apply the $p$-series result.

Comment: But that isn't what I am saying. I am saying the opposite that it is impossible for those values to be larger than n.

Comment: @PaulthePirate: You were quite close! See my updated answer.

Comment: Just to provide an outside opinion: in addition to being correct, this answer *is* quite close to what the OP was doing, hence shows that he was actually on the right track.  (The bit about justifying divergence using $.5 + .25 < 1$ cannot be salvaged though, as far as I can see...)

Comment: I don't understand why not. Isn't that always true?

Comment: @Paul: It is certainly always true that $.5+.25<1,$ but I advise against focusing on that. What matters is that $\min\{.5,.25\}\le1.$ That's what allows us to pull the trick from my answer. Your condition certainly implies that $\min\{.5,.25\}\le1,$ but I fear that fact may mislead you, since (for a contrasting example) we have $5+.75> 1,$ and yet $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{1/2}+n^{3/4}}$$ diverges, using the same kind of reasoning as I gave above.

Comment: But I am saying that as a maximum it still diverges, your example shows a maximum that should converge but doesn't. Mine is something that should diverge at a maximum and does.

Comment: I'm well aware (and noted above) that my example was a contrasting situation. As I said, I'm just advising caution in using your approach.

Comment: @Paul: Belatedly, I realized that I was incorrect about the important point, and why your approach doesn't work. Consider instead the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2+n^{-2}}.$$ This readily satisfies $2+-2<1$ and $\min\{2,-2\}<1,$ and yet it converges! In my comments above, I should have used $\max$ instead of $\min$.